# Booting from a DVD with an ASUS R503U

Tags: boot

I just bought an ASUS R503U, it came with a pre installed Windows 8. I want to change the OS. The problem is I cant seem to boot from the DVD drive. I have accessed the BIOS and only have one boot option "Windows Boot Manager.." with a Fast Boot Option and A Launch CSM option that is disabled. Adding a Boot option involves adding a path, this is where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Asus suggest these steps on their [webpage](http://support.asus.com/Troubleshooting/detail.aspx?SLanguage=en&p=3&m=R503U&s=410&hashedid=n/a&os=&no=1775):

> 1. Insert CD into the optical drive. Your Notebook PC needs to be powered ON.
> 2. Restart the laptop. Press ESC when you see ASUS logo and then select the optical drive (may be labeled as "CD/DVD") from ODD. Press
>      <kbd>Enter</kbd> to boot from the CD.

Comment: Doesnt work..tried that over and over again